# dijit.Tree : Handler expand/collapse event

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.tree

In my APP. Need to use Lazy Loading, so I have to handler the expand event.

I'm using `dijit.Tree` on Dojo library. In the [document API](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/) doesn't have onCollapse/onExpand event.

I have tried to handler onClick event, The event was fired but not well at all, because on click at collapse symbol, Nothing happens.

[image]

Have any idea to handler that event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [`onOpen`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/Tree/onOpen) event might be what you are looking for. Check also [this thread](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/How-to-build-Json-result-for-a-tree-td197752.html).

Comment: Oh!! Why have I Overlook! Thank you very much h4b0.